# jquery show only child

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem : I use classes on a div for simplicity, I would like to show a hidden div after a click, but only on that div, the problem is it shows on all divs, and I can't seem to get it working, here is a jsfiddle with the problem : http://jsfiddle.net/cWNvT/

HTML:

```
<div class="left">
    <a href="#" class="edit-click">Edit</a>
    <div class="edit">
        <p>edit here</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="left">
    <a href="#" class="edit-click">Edit</a>
    <div class="edit">
        <p>edit here</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="left">
    <a href="#" class="edit-click">Edit</a>
    <div class="edit">
        <p>edit here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.edit').hide();
    $('.left a.edit-click').click(function() {
        $('.left').children().show();
    });
});​
```

Anyone have a solution for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cWNvT/2/).**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.edit').hide();
 $('.left a.edit-click').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().children().show();
 });
});
```

All I have done is use `$(this).parent()` instead of using your `$(".left")` selector.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks, it's logical too don't know why I didn't think of this.
I'll accept this answer when I can in 10 minutes, thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

Try finding the parent of the clicked element only, and using its children:

http://jsfiddle.net/cWNvT/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.edit').hide();
   $('.left a.edit-click').click(function(){
       $(this).closest(".left").children().show();
   });
 });
​
```

`$(".left")` selects all elements with class `.left` in the document. `$(this).closest(".left")` finds the first parent of the clicked link that has class `.left`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this:

```
$('.left a.edit-click').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.edit').show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cWNvT/3/